# Set NDK_MODULE_PATH for cocos2dx Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am very new to cocos2dx for android.Now i install cygwin and all enviroment variables . Now when i compile and bulid my project (sample project) it gives message and error that **NDK_MODULE_PATH not found** .
**Here is my LOGCAT:**

```
14:26:15 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project HelloCpp ****
bash C:/Workspace/HelloCpp/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 
NDK_ROOT = C:\android-ndk-r9b
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp/../../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp
Using prebuilt externals
+ 'C:\android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build' -C /cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp/../../../..:/cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp'
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: /cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt    
jni/Android.mk:19: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'hellocpp_shared' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Workspace/HelloCpp'
```

And give error  in file **JNI/android.mk**

on this line :

```
$(call import-module,C:\cocos2d-x-2.2;C:\cocos2d-x-2.2\cocos2dx\platform\third_party\android\prebuilt)
```

any help will be appreciated

**UPDATED**
After Deleting and importing project again without **copy into workspace** its giving this error on run as android project after build project:

```
[2013-11-18 15:30:01 - HelloCpp]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2013-11-18 15:30:01 - HelloCpp]       Unable to add 'C:\cocos2dx2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\assets\fonts\Marker Felt.ttf': Zip add failed
[2013-11-18 15:30:01 - HelloCpp] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'C:\cocos2dx2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
[2013-11-18 15:30:01 - HelloCpp] ERROR: packaging of 'C:\cocos2dx2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_' failed
```

Comment: had you import project with "copy into workspace" option checked?

Comment: Now do one thing remove it from workspace and import again and do not check this option and try

Comment: @BirajZalavadia ok now its giving me another error after doing your steps . Please see my updated part in my question

Comment: This will not run on emulator work with device only. because cocos2dx is uses opengl 2.0 and emulator does not support opengl2.0

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i am running my project on S4 device not on emulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41403/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-user42590)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build_native.sh file add the path of your NDK

# paths

NDK_ROOT = "E:\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e"

Comment: where the build_native.sh is located?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that "Copy project into workspace" is unchecked before importing project into package explorer. This will resolve the error. Also make sure that you have set the environment variable named NDK_ROOT pointing at the url where you have placed the unzipped Android NDK package.