# Error To Run Cocos2d-X sample Android Application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I'm new in Coco2d-x for android . I've configured everything to run cocos2d-x applicaion. But still showing one error when I'm running the application. The error message is given bellow.

(skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
 Unable to add 'D:\AndroidTools\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\projects\TarunCoCos\proj.android\assets\jsb.js': Zip add failed

ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'D:\AndroidTools\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\projects\TarunCoCos\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'

ERROR: packaging of 'D:\AndroidTools\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\projects\TarunCoCos\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_' failed

1. I have installed Python 2.7,3.2 ,Cygwin, Ndk, Android SDK, Eclipse. and showed the path of Cygwin and Android ndk to path section of windows.
2. I have given the chmod -R 777 * permission to my Resorce folder.
3. I have added the library project in eclipse and created project using create_project.py, the language of the project is javascript.
4. I have searched a lot about this error and got some solution but non of them solved my problem.
   eg: [unable to process assets while packaging cocos2d-x android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744119/unable-to-process-assets-while-packaging-cocos2d-x-android)

[Set NDK_MODULE_PATH for cocos2dx Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045033/set-ndk-module-path-for-cocos2dx-android)

Please help me.

[image]